# I am using php with codeigniter framework and i am using filter in my function where user can input 1 filter or user can input 4 inputs(max. 5)

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my table there are 5 rows and i want to get data from the table on the basis of inputs .the rows are name,age,height,weight and class.
If user inputs age= 12 and weight=40 then person with 12 age as well as 40 weight should be shown.
if user inputs only name=jack then persons with name jack should be shown.
if user inputs all five entries then all entries should be matching.
user can input one field or all five fields.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried anything in your code?

Comment: I see no question, i see no code, i see no help for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the inputs to build an associative array which contains the filters you want to apply.

```
$filters = array();

if (!empty($this->input->post('name')))
    $filters['name'] = $this->input->post('name');

if (!empty($this->input->post('age')))
    $filters['age'] = $this->input->post('age');

if (!empty($this->input->post('height')))
    $filters['height'] = $this->input->post('height');

if (!empty($this->input->post('weight')))
    $filters['weight'] = $this->input->post('weight');

if (!empty($this->input->post('class')))
    $filters['class'] = $this->input->post('class');
```

Then, when you are building your query, you just need to iterate over the array:

```
foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
    $this->db->where($key, $value);
}
```

Note the use of `empty()` instead of isset or any manual comparison. [Docs reference](http://php.net/manual/function.empty.php).